# Duplicate mask including animations in vse (2.81)

Tags: video-sequence-editor, masking

I need to duplicate a mask including its animation to invert it and apply it on a movie strip. Is there a possibility to do it? In the dope sheet in mask mode it says "Keyframe pasting is not available..". In recent version it was possible via a number button next the mask name, but this button does not exist in 2.81 any more.
thanks daniel

Answer (score 0):

Save your file with a new name (myproject_tmp.blend), then reopen the original file. File/append, select myproject_tmp, Mask, mymask, Append.

You can now delete myproject_tmp.

*That's a dirty workaround... The miss of this button is either a bug or a regression in my opinion.*

Comment: Great, thanks for your help!